# Maven Installation Error

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-plugin

I am new to maven, so pardon if it is a basic doubt.
I am trying to install a project https://github.com/fommil/netlib-java . Have cloned it on my desktop and tried to install using maven. I am getting following error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:native-maven-plugin:1.0-alpha-7:compile (default-compile) on project netlib-native_ref-osx-x86_64: Error executing command line. Exit code:127 -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :netlib-native_ref-osx-x86_64
```

I looked at the wiki page but didn't understand much. Please give your inputs.

Comment: did you check mvn --version command is displayed your version?

Comment: Yes, Apache Maven 3.0.5 (r01de14724cdef164cd33c7c8c2fe155faf9602da; 2013-02-19 05:51:28-0800)

Comment: Can u just run a compile on the project and check what do u get as the output?